# Decrement cells when records are deleted

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a simple MySQL table (block) as such:

```
SELECT * FROM `block` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `year`, `month`, `day`, `block`;

id      year    month day block te status
20000   2015    12  28  1   100000  1
20001   2015    12  28  2   100000  1
20002   2015    12  28  3   100001  1
20003   2015    12  28  4   100001  1
20004   2015    12  29  1   100001  1
20005   2015    12  29  2   100001  1
20006   2015    12  29  3   100002  1
20066   2015    12  30  1   100003  1
20078   2015    12  30  1   100007  1
20070   2015    12  30  1   100004  1
20067   2015    12  30  2   100003  1
20071   2015    12  30  2   100004  1
20079   2015    12  30  2   100007  1
20072   2015    12  30  3   100004  1
20080   2015    12  30  3   100007  1
20068   2015    12  30  3   100003  1
20069   2015    12  30  4   100003  1
20073   2015    12  30  4   100004  1
20074   2015    12  31  1   100004  1
20075   2015    12  31  1   100000  1
20076   2015    12  31  2   100000  1
20077   2015    12  31  3   100000  1
20007   2016    1   1   1   100017  1
20008   2016    1   1   2   100017  1
20009   2016    1   1   3   100017  1
```

My question is, how can I shift all the remaining rows up if I delete a contiguous section of rows?

For example, if I delete all blocks for 2015-12-28, I want all the remaining blocks to decrement to occupy the unused blocks on the schedule.

Let me know if this is confusing or unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Any table's primary key is not supposed to change. In your case, you want to change the same.

Comment: you want to update your block value on deleting the records correct ??

Comment: I don't want to change the primary key (id). I want to update `year`, `month`, `day`, and `block` for all remaining rows when a chunk is taken out of the middle.

Comment: I realize this probably can't be done solely with MySQL. Perhaps a PHP routine would be better. Maybe I need to do like a strtotime() and do some date math?

Comment: Just to give us an impression, WHY do you want your ids to be continuous? Do you want to order your data by ids? Then there are better ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think a bit more background is required. What is your eventual goal?

Two options...

### First Option

Check out the link below on numbering rows in MySQL. You can use something like this to make your blocks dynamic.
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

### Second Option

If you are pulling data by day, just pull the data in order of the `id` and you can just assume that the blocks are in order in whatever application you use the data in.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if I delete all blocks for 2015-12-28, I want all the remaining blocks to decrement to occupy the unused blocks on the schedule.

You do not actually specify what *decrementing* means. I think you want to shift the *dates* in all the blocks. But look here:

```
20000   2015    12  28  1   100000  1
20001   2015    12  28  2   100000  1
20002   2015    12  28  3   100001  1
20003   2015    12  28  4   100001  1

20004   2015    12  29  1   100001  1
20005   2015    12  29  2   100001  1
20006   2015    12  29  3   100002  1
20066   2015    12  30  1   100003  1
```

We have four blocks for 2015-12-28 and three for 2015-12-29. Say we delete the four 28's. What happens? Do three of the 29's shift to 28's, and the 30 become 29? Or do the three 29's and the 30 shift to fill the four places left by the 28's?

Depending on the strategy you need to choose different strategies. Perhaps you should define what exactly a *block* is, and what data is outside a "block", and supply a couple examples of a shift (with different numbers of days - e.g., 28 28 29 30 and you delete the two 28. BTW, can you delete only one? If so, what would happen then?).

## Say each date can hold a fixed number of records

For example you can first count how many rows you're going to delete

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE day=28 AND month=12 AND year=2015
```

and then select the next items that have a later date. You then shift them, but you need to do this iteratively (once the 29's are gone, the 30's will shift, and so on). This may become quite expensive to calculate.

But in this case you might separate the date from the data:

```
TableA
2015 12 28
2015 12 28
2015 12 28

TableB
20000 100000 1
20001 100000 1
```

Now you need to join the tables in such a way that you can... well, *join* them. *Whatever their cardinality*. You might have a longer TableA than TableB, or vice versa.

This would be pretty easy in some RDBMS. In MySQL it's pretty awful (you can't even use CREATE VIEW to simplify the syntax because you'd need either a variable or a subquery in the view), and for small data sets you'd be better off by selecting TableA, then selecting TableB, and using a cycle in PHP:

```
// Run the query from tableA to get the dates
$TableADataSet = array();
while ($tuple = SQLFetch($rs)) {
    $TableADataSet = $tuple;
}

// Run the query from tableB to get the rest
$TableBDataSet = array();
while ($tuple = SQLFetch($rs)) {
    $TableBDataSet = $tuple;
}

// Now put them together.

for (;;) {
    if (empty($TableADataSet)) {
        if (empty($TableBDataSet)) {
            break;
        }
        $TupleA = $EmptyRowFormattedAsTableA;
        $TupleB = array_pop($TableBDataSet);
    } else {
        $TupleA = array_pop($TableADataSet);
        if (empty($TableBDataSet)) {
            $TupleB = $EmptyRowFormattedAsTableB;
        } else {
            $TupleB = array_pop($TableBDataSet);
        }
    }
    // Now you have a row with dates and data "aligned".
    // Missing data are taken by the sample rows EmptyRowFormattedAs... .
}
```

The result could be (simplifying)

```
2015 12   28      RowA
2015 12   28      RowB
2015 12   29      RowC
NULL NULL NULL    RowD
```

and if you delete RowB, the rightmost part of the rows shifts upwards:

```
2015 12 28 RowA
2015 12 28 RowC
2015 12 29 RowD
```

In MySQL you first need to number the rows, and you have no `RECNO()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` function, so you do it like

```
SELECT @a:=@a+1 AS ranka,data1.* FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY year, month, day ) AS data1, (SELECT @a:=0) AS init1;
```

and get your dates with a row number.

```
1   2015 12 28
2   2015 12 28
3   2015 12 29
```

You do the same for TableB. But now you have to do the "horizontal join" trick. We can be in one of these three cases:

```
B is longer     A is longer    Same length
A B             A B            A B
A B             A B            A B
- B             A -            A B
```

The "A B" part we can get with a JOIN. The "A -" part we get with a LEFT JOIN with a `WHERE TableB.primarykey IS NULL`. The "- B" part we get with a RIGHT JOIN `WHERE TableA.primarykey IS NULL`. Finally we put it all together with a UNION. *And these three queries will need to be made with the awkward syntax above*.

The (quite convoluted) query coming out of all this is

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT @a:=@a+1 AS rank1a, data1.* 
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY year, month, day ) AS data1,
        (SELECT @a:=0) AS init1 
    ) AS ta
JOIN 
    ( SELECT @b:=@b+1 AS rank1b, data2.*
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableB ORDER BY something ) AS data2,
        (SELECT @b:=0) AS init2 ) 
    ) AS tb
ON (rank1a = rank1b)

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT @c:=@c+1 AS rank2a, data3.* 
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY year, month, day ) AS data3,
        (SELECT @c:=0) AS init3
    ) AS tc
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT @d:=@d+1 AS rank2b, data4.*
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableB ORDER BY something ) AS data4,
        (SELECT @d:=0) AS init4 ) 
    ) AS td
ON (rank2a = rank2b) WHERE ( rank2b IS NULL )

UNION

SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT @e:=@e+1 AS rank3a, data5.* 
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY year, month, day ) AS data5,
        (SELECT @e:=0) AS init5
    ) AS te
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT @f:=@f+1 AS rank3b, data6.*
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM TableB ORDER BY something ) AS data6,
        (SELECT @f:=0) AS init6 ) 
    ) AS tf
ON (rank3a = rank3b) WHERE ( rank3a IS NULL )
```

which, from a performance point of view, is probably a hog.